# Identify select option change (change, onchange, click) event through JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any way to know when the `select` option is changed through event other than `onchange` in the `select`?

For example, through jQuery.

```
    $('select').val('2');
    $('#someButton').click(function() { $('select').val('2');});
```

Meaning that if I change the `select` value by click on the button, I may be prompted a message. But when I change the `select` value by choosing option from the `select`, I won't be prompted a message.

Instead of setting a timer scanning the page every single single to check for any `select` value changed (which will heavily bring down the performance), is there any other ways?

Comment: Can include example of `onchange` , `click` handlers at Question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, say you had an event handler

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert('change triggered !');
});
```

that event handler wouldn't be triggered by changing the value programatically, only a user action would trigger that handler, unless it's specifically triggered, meaning we have to do this

```
$('select').val('2').trigger('change');
```

and that gives us the ability to check if the event was fired by a user action or was triggered programatically, by doing

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {

    if ( e.isTrigger ) {
        alert('change triggered programatically !');
    } else {
        alert('change triggered by user !');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cgn6cce1/)